# How do I do a SAML login request, without using a third party control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml

I need to do a SAML login to a site. I know the site is using ComponentPro Ultimate SAML to handle SSO on the Service Provider side... I am functioning as the Identity Provider. I have a sample of how to post it if I purchase the control, but my understanding was that SAML was an open standard, and a specific control shouldn't be needed to do the assertion. Does anyone have a sample of how to format a SAML request in straight C#? Do I need to do anything specail to make it work if the Service Provider is using a 3rd party library like the ComponentPro SAML library?

Comment: You can write your code without any 3rd library. Just read articles about this issue or ask here.  In the end you will get from them a string that you will parse by your self. good luck:)

Comment: It's an open standard, that doesn't mean it will be cost effective for you to reinvent the wheel, and code your own identity provider.

Comment: In my case, I need to allow other clients, who may not be using asp.net or c# to access the same Service Provider. I am creating the sample application, but I can't expect all clients to use the control.

Comment: @ClaytonHall - SAML is based on XML so it does not matter which service providers are using what product as long as the products follow the specification. Although I agree with Aheho that creating a new Identity Provider from scratch may not be the best option. I am not very aware of what options are available in the .net world, but there are many open source SAML products based on Java. If you are not tied to .net for your implementation, you can look around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clayton, we are generating and signing SAML messages with the help of a few classes we wrote (below).  These classes are the culmination of our learnings online.  The assertions are specific to our system, but I do believe it will provide you with a great starting point to build on. For demo purposes, the private key certs are assumed to be located in a folder under the root named "Certificates".  In production environment, they would not be located under the root of the website.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
// Default.aspx
------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SSOClient
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SSOLogin ssoLogin = new SSOLogin();

            ssoLogin.SAML = SSOLogin.SAML_TEMPLATE;
            ssoLogin.ServiceProviderUrl = "";
            ssoLogin.Certificate = new Certificate() { Path = Server.MapPath("/Certificates")  + "/" + "SSOClientCert.pfx", Password = "abcd1234" };
            ssoLogin.Issuer = "SSOClientCert";
            ssoLogin.NameID = "guest";
            ssoLogin.Logout = "http://www.google.com";
            ssoLogin.Controller = "Home";
            ssoLogin.TokenMethod = "SystemID";
            ssoLogin.CustomTokenForVerification = "46";
            ssoLogin.AutoSubmitMessage = false;

            ssoLogin.Post(Response);

            ssoLogin = null;

            /*SSOLogout ssoLogout = new SSOLogout();

            ssoLogout.SAML = SSOLogout.SAML_TEMPLATE;
            ssoLogout.ServiceProviderUrl = "";
            ssoLogout.Certificate = new Certificate() { Path = Server.MapPath("/Certificates") + "/" + "SSOClientCert.pfx", Password = "abcd1234" };
            ssoLogout.Issuer = "SSOClientCert";
            ssoLogout.NameID = "guest";
            ssoLogout.AutoSubmitMessage = false;

            ssoLogout.Post(Response);

            ssoLogout = null;*/
        }
    }
}

------------------------------------------------------------
// Classes
------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;

namespace SSOClient
{
#region Certificate Class
    public class Certificate
    {
        private string _Path = "";
        private string _Password = "";

        public string Path
        {
            get { return this._Path; }
            set { this._Path = value; }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return this._Password; }
            set { this._Password = value; }
        }
    }
#endregion

#region SSOBase Class
    public abstract class SSOBase
    {
        public const string HIDDEN_INPUT_TEMPLATE = @"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}"" value=""{1}"" />";

        private Certificate _Certificate = null;
        private string _ServiceProviderUrl = "";
        private string _ConsumerServicePath = "";
        private string _RelayState = "";
        private string _MessageID = "";
        private string _IssueInstant = "";
        private string _Issuer = "";
        private string _NameID = "";
        private string _SigAlg = "";
        private string _Signature = "";
        private string _SAML = "";
        private string _SAMLSigned = "";

        private bool _AutoSubmitMessage = false;

        public Certificate Certificate
        {
            get { return this._Certificate; }
            set { this._Certificate = value; }
        }

        public string ServiceProviderUrl
        {
            get { return this._ServiceProviderUrl; }
            set { this._ServiceProviderUrl = value; }
        }

        public string ConsumerServicePath
        {
            get { return this._ConsumerServicePath; }
            set { this._ConsumerServicePath = value; }
        }

        public string RelayState
        {
            get { return this._RelayState; }
            set { this._RelayState = value; }
        }

        public string MessageID
        {
            get { return this._MessageID; }
            set { this._MessageID = value; }
        }

        public string IssueInstant
        {
            get { return this._IssueInstant; }
            set { this._IssueInstant = value; }
        }

        public string Issuer
        {
            get { return this._Issuer; }
            set { this._Issuer = value; }
        }

        public string NameID
        {
            get { return this._NameID; }
            set { this._NameID = value; }
        }

        public string SigAlg
        {
            get { return this._SigAlg; }
            set { this._SigAlg = value; }
        }

        public string Signature
        {
            get { return this._Signature; }
            set { this._Signature = value; }
        }

        public string SAML
        {
            get { return this._SAML; }
            set { this._SAML = value; }
        }

        public string SAMLSigned
        {
            get { return this._SAMLSigned; }
            set { this._SAMLSigned = value; }
        }

        public bool AutoSubmitMessage
        {
            get { return this._AutoSubmitMessage; }
            set { this._AutoSubmitMessage = value; }
        }

        public SSOBase()
        {
            this._Certificate = null;
            this._ServiceProviderUrl = "";
            this._ConsumerServicePath = "";
            this._RelayState = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            this._MessageID = String.Format("_{0}", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper());
            this._IssueInstant = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
            this._Issuer = "";
            this._NameID = "";
            this._SigAlg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";
            this._Signature = "";
            this._SAML = "";
            this._SAMLSigned = "";

            this._AutoSubmitMessage = false;
        }

        public XmlDocument Sign(X509Certificate2 x509Certificate, XmlDocument xmlDocument, string referenceId)
        {
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);

            X509Certificate2Collection x509Certificate2Collection;
            try
            {
                x509Certificate2Collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
                x509Certificate2Collection.Add(x509Certificate);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            KeyInfo keyInfo;
            try
            {
                keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

                KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data();

                X509Certificate2Enumerator enumerator = x509Certificate2Collection.GetEnumerator();
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    keyInfoX509Data.AddCertificate(enumerator.Current);
                }

                keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            XmlElement xmlElement = null;

            try
            {
                signedXml.SigningKey = x509Certificate.PrivateKey;
                signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";

                Reference reference = new Reference()
                {
                    Uri = string.Concat("#", referenceId)
                };

                reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());

                XmlDsigExcC14NTransform xmlDsigExcC14NTransform = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("#default samlp saml ds xs xsi"))
                {
                    xmlDsigExcC14NTransform.InclusiveNamespacesPrefixList = "#default samlp saml ds xs xsi";
                }

                reference.AddTransform(xmlDsigExcC14NTransform);

                signedXml.AddReference(reference);
                signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

                signedXml.ComputeSignature();

                this._Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedXml.SignatureValue, Base64FormattingOptions.None);

                xmlElement = signedXml.GetXml();

                XmlNode root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;

                XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);

                nsmgr.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");

                XmlNode issuer = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//saml:Issuer", nsmgr);

                root.InsertAfter(xmlElement, issuer);

                return xmlDocument;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
#endregion

#region SSOLogin Class
    public class SSOLogin : SSOBase
    {
        public const string SAML_TEMPLATE = @"<samlp:Response ID=""@ResponseID"" Version=""2.0"" IssueInstant=""@IssueInstant"" xmlns:samlp=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol""><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"">@Issuer</saml:Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"" /></samlp:Status><saml:Assertion Version=""2.0"" ID=""@AssertionID"" IssueInstant=""@IssueInstant"" xmlns:saml=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion""><saml:Subject><saml:NameID>@NameID</saml:NameID></saml:Subject><saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=""@AuthnInstant"" /><saml:AttributeStatement><saml:Attribute Name=""Logout"" NameFormat=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic""><saml:AttributeValue>@Logout</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=""Controller"" NameFormat=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic""><saml:AttributeValue>@Controller</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=""TokenMethod"" NameFormat=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic""><saml:AttributeValue>@TokenMethod</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=""CustomTokenForVerification"" NameFormat=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic""><saml:AttributeValue>@CustomTokenForVerification</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute></saml:AttributeStatement></saml:Assertion></samlp:Response>";

        private string _AssertionID = "";
        private string _AuthnInstant = "";
        private string _Logout = "";
        private string _Controller = "";
        private string _TokenMethod = "";
        private string _CustomTokenForVerification = "";

        public string AssertionID
        {
            get { return this._AssertionID; }
            set { this._AssertionID = value; }
        }

        public string AuthnInstant
        {
            get { return this._AuthnInstant; }
            set { this._AuthnInstant = value; }
        }

        public string Logout
        {
            get { return this._Logout; }
            set { this._Logout = value; }
        }

        public string Controller
        {
            get { return this._Controller; }
            set { this._Controller = value; }
        }

        public string TokenMethod
        {
            get { return this._TokenMethod; }
            set { this._TokenMethod = value; }
        }

        public string CustomTokenForVerification
        {
            get { return this._CustomTokenForVerification; }
            set { this._CustomTokenForVerification = value; }
        }

        public SSOLogin()
        {
            this._AssertionID = String.Format("_{0}", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper());
            this._AuthnInstant = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
            this._Logout = "";
            this._Controller = "";
            this._TokenMethod = "";
            this._CustomTokenForVerification = "";
        }

        public void Post(HttpResponse response)
        {
            try
            {
                if (base.SAML == "")
                {
                    base.SAML = SAML_TEMPLATE;
                }

                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@ResponseID", base.MessageID);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@IssueInstant", base.IssueInstant);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@Issuer", base.Issuer);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@AssertionID", this._AssertionID);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@AuthnInstant", this._AuthnInstant);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@NameID", base.NameID);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@Logout", this._Logout);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@Controller", this._Controller);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@TokenMethod", this._TokenMethod);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@CustomTokenForVerification", this._CustomTokenForVerification);

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

                xmlDocument.LoadXml(base.SAML);

                XmlDocument xmlDocumentSigned = this.Sign(new X509Certificate2(base.Certificate.Path, base.Certificate.Password), xmlDocument, base.MessageID);

                byte[] signedByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocumentSigned.InnerXml);

                base.SAMLSigned = Convert.ToBase64String(signedByteArray, Base64FormattingOptions.None);

                IDictionary<string, string> hiddenInputDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                hiddenInputDic.Add("SAMLResponse", base.SAMLSigned);
                hiddenInputDic.Add("RelayState", base.RelayState);

                StringBuilder hiddenInputs = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (string hiddenInputName in hiddenInputDic.Keys)
                {
                    string hiddenFieldValue = hiddenInputDic[hiddenInputName];

                    hiddenInputs.AppendFormat(SSOBase.HIDDEN_INPUT_TEMPLATE + Environment.NewLine,
                        hiddenInputName,
                        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(hiddenFieldValue));
                }

                string samlForm = String.Format(@"
<form id=""samlForm"" action=""{0}"" method=""post"">
    {1}
    <input type=""submit"" name=""btnLogin"" value=""Login"" />
</form>",
                        String.Format("{0}{1}", this.ServiceProviderUrl, base.ConsumerServicePath),
                        hiddenInputs.ToString());

                string pageTemplate = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
    <body{0}>
        <h3>SAML SSO - Login Example</h3>
        <p>Please click the Login button to Login.</p>
        <div>
            {1}
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h3>SAML Form</h3>
        <div>
            <textarea cols=""100"" rows=""50"">
                {2} 
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";

                HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

                StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

                html.AppendFormat(pageTemplate,
                    base.AutoSubmitMessage ? @" onload=""document.getElementById('samlForm').submit();""" : "",
                    samlForm,
                    httpContext.Server.HtmlEncode(samlForm));

                StreamWriter outputStream = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream);
                outputStream.Write(html.ToString());
                outputStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                response.Write(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
#endregion

#region SSOLogout Class
    public class SSOLogout : SSOBase
    {
        public const string SAML_TEMPLATE = @"<saml:LogoutRequest ID=""@RequestID"" Version=""2.0"" IssueInstant=""@IssueInstant"" xmlns:saml=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol""><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"">@Issuer</saml:Issuer><saml:NameID xmlns:saml=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"">@NameID</saml:NameID></saml:LogoutRequest>";

        public SSOLogout()
        {
        }

        public void Post(HttpResponse response)
        {
            try
            {
                if (base.SAML == "")
                {
                    base.SAML = SAML_TEMPLATE;
                }

                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@RequestID", base.MessageID);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@IssueInstant", base.IssueInstant);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@Issuer", base.Issuer);
                base.SAML = base.SAML.Replace("@NameID", base.NameID);

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

                xmlDocument.LoadXml(base.SAML);

                XmlDocument xmlDocumentSigned = this.Sign(new X509Certificate2(base.Certificate.Path, base.Certificate.Password), xmlDocument, base.MessageID);

                byte[] signedByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocumentSigned.InnerXml);

                base.SAMLSigned = Convert.ToBase64String(signedByteArray, Base64FormattingOptions.None);

                IDictionary<string, string> hiddenInputDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                hiddenInputDic.Add("SAMLRequest", base.SAMLSigned);
                hiddenInputDic.Add("RelayState", base.RelayState);
                hiddenInputDic.Add("SigAlg", base.SigAlg);
                hiddenInputDic.Add("Signature", base.Signature);

                StringBuilder hiddenInputs = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (string hiddenInputName in hiddenInputDic.Keys)
                {
                    string hiddenFieldValue = hiddenInputDic[hiddenInputName];

                    hiddenInputs.AppendFormat(SSOBase.HIDDEN_INPUT_TEMPLATE + Environment.NewLine,
                        hiddenInputName,
                        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(hiddenFieldValue));
                }

                string samlForm = String.Format(@"
<form id=""samlForm"" action=""{0}"" method=""post"">
    {1}
    <input type=""submit"" name=""btnLogout"" value=""Logout"" />
</form>", 
                    String.Format("{0}{1}", this.ServiceProviderUrl, base.ConsumerServicePath),
                    hiddenInputs.ToString());

                string pageTemplate = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
    <body{0}>
        <h3>SAML SSO - Logout Example</h3>
        <p>Please click the Logout button to Logout.</p>
        <div>
            {1}
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h3>SAML Form</h3>
        <div>
            <textarea cols=""100"" rows=""50"">
                {2} 
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";

                HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

                StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

                html.AppendFormat(pageTemplate,
                    base.AutoSubmitMessage ? @" onload=""document.getElementById('samlForm').submit();""" : "",
                    samlForm,
                    httpContext.Server.HtmlEncode(samlForm));

                StreamWriter outputStream = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream);
                outputStream.Write(html.ToString());
                outputStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                response.Write(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
#endregion
}
```